# Class property error "Object is required", but works normally

Tags: excel, vba

Strange problem with vba. I'm trying to create module with table decoration properties. In form user selects color for table header background. Color is changed, but there is error.
How can I fix this? Ideas?

DecorationModule:

```
Private sHeaderTextBackground As Double
Public sHeaderRange As Range

Public Sub initVars()
    Set sHeaderRange = Range("A1:F1")
End Sub

Public Property Let HeaderTextBackground(ByVal color As Double)
    Let sHeaderTextBackground = color
End Property

Public Property Get HeaderTextBackground() As Double
    HeaderTextBackground = sHeaderTextBackground
End Property
```

Code in form:

```
Private Sub changeStyleApplyButton_Click()
    'Call DecorationModule.initVars

    If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogEditColor).Show(40) = True Then
        MsgBox (VarType(ThisWorkbook.Colors(40))) '<--- 5 = vbDouble
        DecorationModule.HeaderTextBackground = ThisWorkbook.Colors(40) <---Error here
        DecorationModule.sHeaderRange.Interior.color = DecorationModule.HeaderTextBackground
    End If
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue - works fine in my test of it. What's the error?

Comment: Object is required in line DecorationModule.HeaderTextBackground = ThisWorkbook.Colors(40). Header color is changed, but after that show up modal with error. I do it in Excel 2003. Maybe it can be importart.Tryed print in Property Let some string in MsgBox before "Let sHeaderTextBackground = color", but it not shows up. It really blows my mind.

Comment: Did you in fact name the module `DecorationModule`? That error happens if you left the module with the default name e.g. `Module1`.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem. Did you put a variable in the form that refers to the module? Like `Dim dm As New DecorationModule` and then use `dm.HeaderTextBackground = ThisWorkbook.Colors(40)` Also is it a ClassModule or just Module?

Actually, this only works with a ClassModule. I assumed that it was.

Comment: GSerg, No, name is correct: "DecorationModule"

Comment: And it is indeed a standard module, as opposed to a class module?

Comment: erazorv4, GSerg, Tryed standart module and ClassModule. I want to use it without create an instance. Like static class. It is possible?

Comment: You don't "try", you use one or the other because they have different usage patterns. The error does not occur with a standard module, which you appear to want to use.

Comment: Try putting the code that is in DecorationModule into a Module instead of Class Module. And then the code should work just like that.

Comment: GSerg, erazorv4, Again create standart Module with name DecorationModule and deleted ClassModule. Error changes to "Object variable or With block variable not set" in line "DecorationModule.sHeaderRange.Interior.color = DecorationModule.HeaderTextBackground". But color still changes properly

Comment: And when you uncomment the `Call DecorationModule.initVars`?

Comment: erazorv4, Damn, it's my fault. Thanks. Now works, but I still doesn't understand why color was changed if property was threw an error.

Comment: Glad I could help. :) I don't know why it was still changing the color though.
I'm gonna write these comments into an answer in a bit. So this doesn't stay open.

Comment: erazorv4, really strange behavior) Thanks to you and  GSerg for help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future people with this error: Make sure you have named the `Module` properly, and that you do not have any spelling mistakes. That should cover most of the errors.

---

The problem was that a `ClassModule` was used instead of a `Module`. The code should be pasted into a `Module` (with the right name) and then the code works. Make sure to initialize the `sHeaderRange` before the code is executed. If you want to make sure it is only initialized once you can change the `initVars()` sub to:

```
Public Sub initVars()
    If sHeaderRange Is Nothing Then
        Set sHeaderRange = Range("A1:F1")
    End If
End Sub
```